# JRuby Net:Http get issue with unicode characters in response body

Tags: unicode, jruby

I have a problem with JRuby in 1.9 mode. I am fetching some CSV file through HTTP

```
Net::HTTP.start(csv_uri.host) do |http|
  puts http.get(csv_uri.path).body
  File.open(csv_file_path, "w") { |csv| csv.write(http.get(csv_uri.path).body) }
end
```

In response I see strange characters in place of polish chars 'ą', 'ś' etc. Is it possible to get this data in JRuby with proper character encoding?

Answer (score 0):

Is the data you are expecting in UTF-8 or iso-8859-2?  Depending on the encoding, you may have to force the encoding to either:

```
http.get(csv_uri.path).body.encode(Encoding::UTF_8)
```

or

```
http.get(csv_uri.path).body.encode(Encoding::ISO_8859_2)
```

Comment: @Sebastian Do you know what the encoding of the csv file is, or can we access that file somewhere? What version of jruby are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Might the problem be in the writing to file? Try

File.open(csv_file_path, "w:utf-8")